# Decommission Active Directory Certificate Services server: side effects

Tags: active-directory, ad-certificate-services

I have a private domain to which I later *added* AD CS, NPS, RRAS and setup SSTP VPN access.  I used AD CS to create a certificate for the SSTP connection and DynDNS to get me in from outside.  Everything has worked fine for years.  I would now like to decommission that machine and I have researched the steps I will need to take to remove the above roles properly.

When looking at the certificates issued by the AD CS server, I see Computer (Machine), Basic EFS, Kerberos Auth., Domain Controller Auth. and Directory Email Replication certificates.  These are **besides** my remote computer authentication (Web Server) certificate.  Since I am still a noob (in over my head?), would there be a problem with my private domain if/when I revoke all these certificates prior to decommissioning?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the point of revoking the certificates if the CRL isn't available?

Comment: @Greg Askew ... Thank you for that reminder.  So then, can you think of any problems, due to those certificates being issued, if I just decommission the AD CS server?

Comment: Just a note, when decomming, migrating, or replacing AD CS servers in the past, I ensure that the CRL Distribution Point is still available - easy with a DNS alias and a small-footprint webserver.  To that end, you could probably check the IIS logs for the current CDP to see if there have been any hits, that may give you a clue as to which clients are still hitting services that are secured by the certificates issued by the CA